# Overflow: hidden - leaves tiny gaps close to the border

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know how to get rid of these tiny empty spaces visible close to the border of a parent after toggling the element?

At the same time, I can't understand why it doesn't seem to be an issue in the original code that I used ([source](https://codepen.io/liamj/pen/vvdRdR)), and it works fine without declaring a display type of the parent (in my code to make overflow work I had to say display type, I've chosen flex)

```css
html {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
  width: 300px;
}
input[id="twoPlayersMode"],
input[id="AImode"] {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
input[id="twoPlayersMode"]:checked + label::after,
input[id="AImode"]:checked + label::after {
  transform: scale(4.4);
}
label[for="twoPlayersMode"],
label[for="AImode"] {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-clip: content-box;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  user-select: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.04rem;
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
  border: 0.3rem solid black;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 black;
}
label[for="twoPlayersMode"]::after,
label[for="AImode"]::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, white 24%, black 25%, black 100%);
}
label[for="twoPlayersMode"]:active,
label[for="AImode"]:active {
  top: 3px;
  box-shadow: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="twoPlayersMode" name="gameModeRadio" />
  <label for="twoPlayersMode">Play against another player</label>

  <input type="radio" id="AImode" name="gameModeRadio" />
  <label for="AImode">Play against AI</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by using `rem` values in `border-radius`, `border`, and `letter-spacing`. The original code resets the `font-size` to `10px`, and yours is the `initial`, `16px`. This makes an issue with the rest of the `rem` values since they scale with the root font size.

Using relative values is a great practice, but some things should still be set in absolute values.

Here is your code with the fixed values:

```css
html {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     font-size: 16px;
}
 div {
     width: 300px;
}
 input[id="twoPlayersMode"], input[id="AImode"] {
     height: 0;
     width: 0;
     visibility: hidden;
}
 input[id="twoPlayersMode"]:checked + label::after, 
 input[id="AImode"]:checked + label::after {
     transform: scale(4.2);
}
 label[for="twoPlayersMode"], label[for="AImode"] {
     display: flex;
     position: relative;
     overflow: hidden;
     background-clip: content-box;
     justify-content: center;
     cursor: pointer;
     outline: none;
     user-select: none;
     color: black;
     font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
     font-size: 1rem;
     letter-spacing: 0.4px;
     padding: 1.5rem 1rem;
     border-radius: 4px;
     border: 3px solid black;
     background: white;
     box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 black;
}
 label[for="twoPlayersMode"]::after, label[for="AImode"]::after {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     transform: scale(0);
     transition: transform .3s ease-in;
     mix-blend-mode: difference;
     background: radial-gradient(circle at center,white 24%,black 25%,black 100%);
}
 label[for="twoPlayersMode"]:active, label[for="AImode"]:active {
     top: 3px;
     box-shadow: none;
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
<input type="radio" id="twoPlayersMode" name="gameModeRadio" />
<label for="twoPlayersMode">Play against another player</label>

<input type="radio" id="AImode" name="gameModeRadio" />
<label for="AImode">Play against AI</label>
</div>
```

Comment: You might grab the compiled CSS from the updated snippet on the question to better demonstrate your solution.

Comment: There seems to be a minor bug with the effect on the top button fill, but it only happens in Stack Overflow. Not sure why.